# Why is the Digital Signature not visible in some PDF documents using iText 7.1.11?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

My project digitally signs PDF documents using a digital certificate and displays the signature at the bottom left of the document. It had always worked well until now, there are some documents that are digitally signed but it is not shown although it is recognized that the rectangle where it is visible is. Could someone help with this, I leave a snippet that handles the digital signature.
[Here](https://mega.nz/file/dDZl2aDZ#HHbPz5YLk2Zv2nXMLYwAt_aWgSKlz0TDQqvA0lJhVlg) I leave a screenshot of how the digital signature is in a PDF document, I show it in the lower left corner of the document.

**EXAMPLES**

In this [link](https://mega.nz/folder/dXIzjYYR#_X8PlSrkMfd97DzSdboNVg) I have shared example pdf documents of the problem and without it, I will detail them below:

- `ok_unsigned.pdf` file: it is a document that when passing through my project is signed well, becoming the `ok_signed.pdf` file (this is the norm so far)
- `ok_signed.pdf` file: it is the digitally signed `ok_unsigned.pdf` file, it is a case of success
- `bad_unsigned.pdf` file: it is a blank document that when digitally signed (`bad_signed.pdf`) the issue in question appears
- `bad_signed.pdf` file: it is a document with the issue in question, digitally signed but without visually seeing the signature field.

**CODE**

````
        try {
            BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Security.addProvider(providerBC);

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore), password);
            String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
            Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
            PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password);

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest));
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, fos, new StampingProperties());
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 150, 50);
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
            
            appearance.setPageRect(rect)
                    .setCertificate(chain[0])
                    .setReasonCaption("")
                    .setLocationCaption("")
                    .setSignatureCreator("SignerJAGC - iText 7.1.11")
                    .setPageNumber(1);
            signer.setFieldName("Banca en Línea - Envío de Documentos");
            signer.setSignDate(new GregorianCalendar());
            signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

            IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            IExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, providerBC.getName());

            signer.signDetached(digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, SUBFILTER);
            System.out.println("SIGNED");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Please share an example PDF signed by your code on which the signature does not appear. The obvious reason may be that the coordinates you gave are not in the visible page area (every page may have its own coordinate system, the lower left corner merely often is the origin) or that the PDF is a XFA form. But it might be caused by something different, too.

Comment: Sorry @mkl, I cannot share any PDF documents as my employment contract prohibits it. The coordinates cannot be the problem because if you see my fragment I only move 10 pixels from the point (0, 0) for both X and Y. Although I cannot share any PDF document in this [link](https://mega.nz/file/dDZl2aDZ#HHbPz5YLk2Zv2nXMLYwAt_aWgSKlz0TDQqvA0lJhVlg) I leave a screenshot of a signed document.

Comment: Without a PDF illustrating the issue i cannot analyze further than my original comment.

Comment: @mkl, I'll try to see how I share a PDF document with that characteristics. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mkl, in this [link](https://mega.nz/folder/dXIzjYYR#_X8PlSrkMfd97DzSdboNVg) I have shared example pdf documents with the issue and without it, I will detail them in my question in the **EXAMPLES** section:

Comment: Indeed, just like guessed in my first comment here, *the coordinates you gave are not in the visible page area.* As @iPDFdev explained, the page with the signature widget has a cropbox of `[ 0.0 432.0 612.100037 1224.099976 ]`, i.e. its lower left corner has the coordinates (0,432), so your `Rectangle(10, 10, 150, 50)` is completely below your page.

Comment: That was it, I already saw it. I already fixed it and everything works out. Thank you very much @mkl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mkl said your coordinates might be outside of the page visible area as not all PDF pages have the bottom left corner at (0, 0).

Try creating the signature rectangle like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
    yourPageCropBoxLowerLeftX + 10, 
    yourPageCropBoxLowerLeftY + 10, 
    yourPageCropBoxLowerLeftX + 10 + yourSignatureWidth, 
    yourPageCropBoxLowerLeftY + 10 + yourSignatureHeight);
```

You just have to see how you can read the page's crop box coordinates, the lower left corner, as I'm not familiar with iText API.

Comment: I don't think they are the coordinates because the PDF readers tell me that there is "something" (the digital signature) in that area. Thank you for your comment, I will keep it in mind and I will review everything with it in mind.

Comment: JAGC as @mkl guessed, your page crop box lower left coordinate is (0,432) while your signature is placed at (10, 10), so it is outside the page visible area.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @iPDFdev. I must use the CropBox coordinates of the page.